# Find continued fractions and corresponding rationals

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

I want to compute the rationals that the continued fractions $[4;2,1,3,1,2,4]$ and $[0;1,2,3,4,3,2,1]$ represent.

Also, I want to find the continued fractions of the rationals $-\frac{19}{51}, \frac{187}{57}, \frac{71}{55}, \frac{118}{303}$.

Do we compute the rational that the continued fraction $[4;2,1,3,1,2,4]$ represent as follows?

$$x=4+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{x}}}}}}}}$$

If so, how can we easily simplify in order to find $x$ ?

Also, how can we find the continued fraxtion of some given rational?

Comment: Are you familiar with the convergents? Also, I would take a look at your final line inside the CF, I believe that should just be a 4

Comment: How do we use the convergents? Could you give me a hint? @bounceback So the last term should be $2+\frac{1}{4}$ ?

Comment: Work through them until you get so far as the answer. And, yes. eg. $c_0 = 4, c_1 = 4 + \frac{1}{2} = 4.5, c_2 = 4 + \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{1}} = 4.333...$

Comment: Evinda, I put in the clearest way to do these visually, in an answer. It will help you if you do the last one, as a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

here is one of them. Given a fraction, you are just doing the Euclidean algorithm

$$ \frac{ 187 }{ 57 } = 3 +  \frac{ 16 }{ 57 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 57 }{ 16 } = 3 +  \frac{ 9 }{ 16 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 16 }{ 9 } = 1 +  \frac{ 7 }{ 9 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 9 }{ 7 } = 1 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 7 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 7 }{ 2 } = 3 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2 }{ 1 } = 2 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
 & & 3 & & 3 & & 1 & & 1 & & 3 & & 2 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 10 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }   & &   \frac{ 23 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 82 }{ 25 }   & &   \frac{ 187 }{ 57 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
Note how it begins with two **pretend** convergents, $0/1$ and $1/0,$ after which each "digit" of $  3;  3,  1,  1,  3,  2  $ tells you how to produce the next convergent. As a rule using 2 by 2 matrices, given "digit" $d$ and consecutive convergents $(p/q)$ and $(r/s),$ we get a revised consecutive pair $(r/s)$ then $((p+rd)/(q+sd))$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
p & r \\
q & s
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
1 & d
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
r & p+rd \\
s & q+sd
\end{array}
\right)
$$

An example I made up:
 $$ \frac{ 81201 }{ 56660 } = 1 +  \frac{ 24541 }{ 56660 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 56660 }{ 24541 } = 2 +  \frac{ 7578 }{ 24541 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 24541 }{ 7578 } = 3 +  \frac{ 1807 }{ 7578 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 7578 }{ 1807 } = 4 +  \frac{ 350 }{ 1807 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1807 }{ 350 } = 5 +  \frac{ 57 }{ 350 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 350 }{ 57 } = 6 +  \frac{ 8 }{ 57 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 57 }{ 8 } = 7 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 8 }{ 1 } = 8 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 4 & & 5 & & 6 & & 7 & & 8 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 10 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 43 }{ 30 }   & &   \frac{ 225 }{ 157 }   & &   \frac{ 1393 }{ 972 }   & &   \frac{ 9976 }{ 6961 }   & &   \frac{ 81201 }{ 56660 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$

**WORKSHEET:**  See if you can fill in the  convergents for your $[4;2,1,3,1,2,4]$ question
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 & & 4 & & 2 & & 1 & & 3 & & 1 & & 2 & & 4 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ ? }{ ? }   & &   \frac{ ? }{ ? }   & &   \frac{ ? }{ ? }   & &   \frac{ ? }{ ? }   & &   \frac{ ? }{ ? }    & &   \frac{ ? }{ ? } 
 \end{array}
 $$